# Spanish text is not displayed properly when value is set to input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to set a spanish text to a input field and it doesn't seem to show up properly.
But the same text shows up fine if its inside a div or when it is already set as a value to input field.

HTML

```
<div>Cuenta de Ahorros  Persona F&iacute;sica</div>
<input id="txt2" type="text" value="Cuenta de Ahorros  Persona F&iacute;sica" />
<input id="txt" type="text" value="" />
```

JS

```
$('#txt').val('Cuenta de Ahorros  Persona F&iacute;sica');   //does not work properly
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/v8p0efzx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use

```
$('#txt').val($('<div>').html('Cuenta de Ahorros  Persona F&iacute;sica').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, `&iacute;` is just a string of eight characters, though you can have it interpreted as an HTML entity reference by assigning it to the `innerHTML` property or using e.g. some jQuery code that does something similar.

There are other escapes for use in JavaScript strings, such as `\u00ED`, but the simplest approach (and the way to keep your source code readable) is to write the characters as such, e.g.

```
 $('#txt').val('Cuenta de Ahorros  Persona Física');
```

You need to make sure the [character encoding](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php) is properly set and declared, but this should be taken care of in any case.