# PHP, MySQL, quotes and inputs fields

Tags: php, mysql, input, quotes

I'm trying to build an edit page to edit a title.

This title would be displayed in both an "h3" tag and an input field.
When the user is happy with the title, he submits it to mysql where it is saved.
The page refreshes and he can see his new title within the "h3" tag and the input field.

The problem is that, when quotes are involved in the title, I don"t get the same result in the "h3" tag and the input field.

Here is how I retrieve the variable to send it to the database:

```
$title_set = $_POST['title'];
```

And here is how I display the variable in both the  tag and input field:

```
$title_get = $result['denomination'];
```

With this here is the display for the title: *L'appel de la "forêt"*

```
$title_set = $_POST['title'];
$title_get = $result['denomination'];

<h3>  -> No output
Input -> No output
```

Variation 1:

```
$title_set = addslashes($_POST['title']);
$title_get = $result['denomination'];

<h3>  -> L'appel de la "forêt"
Input -> L'appel de la
```

Variation 2:

```
$title_set = addslashes($_POST['title']);
$title_get = stripslashes($result['denomination']);

<h3>  -> L'appel de la "forêt"
Input -> L'appel de la
```

Variation 3:

```
$title_set = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['title']);
$title_get = $result['denomination'];

<h3>  -> L'appel de la "forêt"
Input -> L'appel de la
```

Obviously, there are differences in the way a title tag and an input field manage to display dynamic data with quotes, input fields being more restrictive.

So, what should I do?

My pages, scripts and database are encoded in UTF_8

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. You may very well be injecting characters that SQL doesn't agree with.

Comment: And look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831176/spanish-text-is-not-displayed-properly-when-value-is-set-to-input-field ( if it is an `input` problem ).

Comment: I'm not convinced as the "h3" tag displays it well while the input field displays it partially. So it seems that it's not related to SQL error, is it?

Comment: A tip, in `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_SESSION`, ... , use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before inserting data to the database, use an escaping function like mysql_real_escape_string(). Or even better, switch to PDO so you can use prepared queries and submit the data as a parameter. This protects against SQL injection. See [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Before echoing to HTML the dynamic content you fetched from the database, encode it with htmlspecialchars(). This protects against Cross-Site Scripting (XSS). See [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)

Further reading: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Top_Ten_Cheat_Sheet for more on injection and XSS risks and remedies.

Comment: This is a test case. If you read my question until the end, you'll see that the "mysql_real_escape_string()" is part of it. Of course, eventually the data will be secured.

Comment: The second part is very relevant, thank you. By adding htmlspecialchars() before the display, everything is fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` when inserting the value into the MySQL query. Otherwise, the quotes in the input will cause SQL syntax errors. It would be even better if you converted to MySQLI or PDO, and used query parameters instead of string concatenation.

You should use `htmlentities()` when retrieving the data and displaying it on a web page. This will produce proper HTML encoding of all special characters.

Comment: I did try htmlentities along with mysql_real_escape_string() and this is what I get: L'appel de la "forÃªt" in both cases

Comment: What version of PHP? Before 5.4 the default encoding was ISO-8859-1, since then it's UTF-8.

Comment: 5.3 which explains it.